Gcloud node deployment - gcloud app deploy with latest node version
I was using nodejs 16 for my gcloud node application.
Now I am getting warning and unable to deploy nodejs app to gcloud.
I am trying to re-upload with latest nodejs version.
This is my cloudbuild.yaml

# Install node packages
- name: node:18.7.0
  entrypoint: npm
  args: ['install', '--ignore-engines']

# Deploy to google cloud app engine
- name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
  args: ['app', 'deploy']

This is my app.yaml file
env: flex

env_variables:
  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: "config/project-google-sheet-credentials-prod.json"
  PROD: true
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 4
  disk_size_gb: 10
network:
  name: projects/myproject/global/networks/vpc1

I am keep getting error like this:
Step #1: npm ERR! path /workspace/node_modules/fibers
Step #1: npm ERR! command failed
Step #1: npm ERR! command sh /tmp/install-13dd1c3c.sh
Step #1: npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/workspace/node_modules/fibers/build'
Step #1: npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o
Step #1: npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/workspace/node_modules/fibers/build'
Step #1: npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/workspace/node_modules/fibers/build'
Step #1: npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o
Step #1: npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/workspace/node_modules/fibers/build'
Step #1: npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
Step #1: npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
Step #1: npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.7.0 | linux | x64
Step #1: npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.2 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
Step #1: npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.7.0/node-v18.7.0-headers.tar.gz
Step #1: npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.7.0/node-v18.7.0-headers.tar.gz
Step #1: npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.7.0/SHASUMS256.txt
Step #1: npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.7.0/SHASUMS256.txt
Step #1: npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3```


Your question lacks detail but, it appears you're using fibers and that npm page says "Fibers is not compatible with nodejs v16.0.0 or later.".

By way of general guidance, it is a bad practice to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS when deploying to Google compute services. These services use Application Default Credentials to authenticate using the Service Account that corresponds to the deployment. When you deploy to App Engine, you can specify the Service Account with gcloud app deploy --service-account=${FOO} and the credentials will be provided by the Metadata service. This is more portable and more secure.

Thank you @DazWilkin. I will update GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.
I am not using fibers anywhere. But not getting why I am getting this error. Fibers is not there in package.json or node_modules.
Any suggetions?

Please update your question to include package.json dependencies; don't forget to obfuscate anything confidential. It may be that one of your dependencies requires fibers.

@DazWilkin I have updated!
